# NSMutableDictionary not retaining values

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am semi-new to Objective-c and confused with why my NSMutableDictionary is not retaining information. I am declaring my variable in the header file:

```
@interface view_searchResults : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableDictionary *imageDicationary;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *imageDictionary;
```

Then in my .m file, I have the following:

```
@synthesize imageDictionary;

-(UIImage *)getImageForURL:(NSURL*)url {

    UIImage*image;
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    [imageDictionary setObject:image forKey:@"test"];

    if([imageDictionary objectForKey:@"test"]){

        NSLog(@"Exists");

    }

}
```

There is obviously other code to support this, but I can confirm that a URL is being passed, and the file is downloading correctly elsewhere. Also, I can confirm that this function is being executed, and I am not referring to the NSMutableDictionary anywhere else in the document.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where do you create your NSMutable dictionary? If this really is all the code you have you need to create the dictionary:

```
@implementation view_searchResults 
- (id) init;{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        imageDicationary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    // should also be released in dealloc.
    }
    return self;
}
```

If this is the error then the reason you are not causing a crash is because in objective-C it is valid to send a message to the nil object - it just does nothing.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I assumed that defining it initially was sufficient, but that was obviously not the case. It's a long road from PHP to Objective-C. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem. Please mark me as the correct answer :-) note also that I've edited the code I provided.

Answer (score 1):

You havent told us whether the "Exists" NSLog is executed, you also are NOT returning the image.

In other words, I fail to see your problem

Answer (score 0):

Has `imageDictionary` been initialized? (alloc/init?)